# Font tag automatically wrapped in my html

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am not using any font tag in my HTML. Even in view source there is no font tag but after page rendering there are some font wrap on DOM with color and face property as below:

```
<font color="#222222" face="Georgia, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif">
```

If I disable the JavaScript same is happening as it is. Hence it is not coming from JS.

I checked in Chrome and Mozilla latest version.

Any one have any idea regarding this?

Comment: can you share your website or its environment with us?

Comment: I think browser have default font in Firefox type this in the adress bar `about:preferences#content`

Comment: Just to make sure: The font tag is not inserted by a CMS?

Comment: I had the same issue in Google Chrome DevTools. I disabled JS in the DevTools, did a Empty Cache Hard Reload, enabled JS in the DevTools and again Empty Cabche Hard Reload and now no more <font> tags. Not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming here later on, this is a browser issue I have faced. It was happening because of google translation. Turning off google translation resolves the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh it is the cause i was stuck for hours because of this . Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

If someone is encountering a similar problem and is not resolved by using the above methods. It might be worthwhile to verify if the text or string in question includes any HTML tags. These can either be escaped or entirely removed to solve the issue. This approach was effective in my case, especially because the data I was working with was being retrieved from a database and included HTML tags